# Django app connect with external API

Tags: python, django, api

I have this web app where I upload files and do some stuff with them. 
There's been a request to connect this app with another site and upload files (upon request) form the app to the site. This site provides an API and with it python code to interact with that. Since I am one year old in programming years I don't quite get the API concept. All I know so far is that it's something in the middle that handles requests. 
Anyway,

The code provided(from the site) has a class and several methods to that class like so:

```
class ApiClient(object):
    def method1(self,param1):
```

Since I haven't,so far, worked with external APIs before I don't know how to handle it and have some questions.

1.Regardless the `class ApiClinet(object)` I get that they provide python code so the class is an object, but how do I handle it? Do I make it a `models.Model`?

2.Adittionaly to my first question,do I store the information for this in the database? So do I need fields?

thanks in advnace!

Comment: Since this site provides an API, have you read its documentation? Do they explain how to *consume* that API? Maybe [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) will be handy for your use case.

Comment: They do use requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"API' means "Application Programming Interface", which actually means a whole lot of mostly unrelated stuffs...  But when it comes to web, "API" usually means "something you can interact with by sending HTTP requests".

Sometimes you'll only have the description of the endpoint urls, what's expected in the request and what's supposed to be returned in the response, and you have to write all the client code by yourself (using `urllib` or - better - `requests`), but sometimes someone (eventually the author of the API) also provides a client library for your language of choice, so it's just a matter of using this client library.

In your case it seems you already have the client, so it's just a matter of using it, ie:

```
from yourapi import ApiClient
client = ApiClient(<probably some API key needed here>)
result = client.fetch_something(some, args)
```

What methods are available and what they return is of course totally specific to this API and should be documented somewhere.

What you do with results is totally up to you and depends on what your project's requirements are so no one can answer this question.

Comment: Thank you @bruno for your great answer. One follow up. Can I interact with ApiClient(object) as it is? Without making it a Django model? And if so where do I put the code for that class. On my models.py?

Comment: > "Can I interact with ApiClient(object) as it is? Without making it a Django model?" Well yes of course, why ? Django "models" are just the ORM part, you only use it for what you want to store in a SQL database (and even then you can do without). And you can put your api client code wherever you see fit, that's all plain Python stuff you know, nothing magical here.

Comment: You are right! It's just I  have interact so much with Django from the beginning of my programming learning, I forget a  little bit about plain python stuff. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```py
import requests
REMOTE_API_URL = "https://google.com/blabla"

class ApiClient(models.Model):
    file = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        post_data = {'remote_api_file_field': self.file}
        requests.post(REMOTE_API_URL, data=post_data)
        super(ApiClient).save()
```

Also see; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading

Comment: Just because the OP doesn't quite grasp what's an API is and how to use it doesn't mean you should post something _that_ inept.